# Problem with installing psycopg2cffi on m1

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2, apple-m1

Does anyone try to install psycopg2cffi on mac m1?

psycopg2 works fine for me,
for psycopg2cffi I got this error

I'm doing

`pip3 install psycopg2cffi`

and then get

```
    ld: warning: dylib (/opt/homebrew/lib/libpq.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (12.0) than being linked (11.0)
  ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/lib/libpq.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/folders/v3/zqxmc7t138n9_qn7n38680dm0000gn/T/pip-install-swb5z_gs/psycopg2cffi_25da3ba0978a417b8f4df8a82525c22f/psycopg2cffi/_impl/libpq.py", line 2, in <module>
      from psycopg2cffi._impl._libpq import ffi, lib as libpq
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2cffi._impl._libpq'
```